# Limiting raster processing area by geometry

Tags: arcgis-pro, rasterization

I have a map with a vector feature dataset of soil types, and a feature dataset of points.

[image: Map of soil types and point features]

I want to transform the soil dataset to raster, but I only need the results around the points (a buffer with specific distance around all these points) and my area of calculation is huge so processing the whole area takes a lot of time. The normal process that I will have to go through is shown below (left to right). My desired output is the clipped rasterized data on the right side.

[image: The normal process]

Is there any way that instead of using "polygon to raster" for the whole area and then clipping the raster using a buffer around the points, I create the buffer first and then limit the calculations inside the buffer? Calculating the whole area needs a lot of time and creates rasters as huge as 10 GB and I have to do this for many layers.

Comment: Please add a graphic to show what you mean, since this is either an "Of course" or a "Why would you want to do that?" (or both)

Comment: I want to extract image chips to build a deep learning model with multiple rasters combined into a composite raster. I want to know if I can by any means limit the rasterization to approximately the areas that are going to be used in the chips instead of calculating the whole surface and not using 60%+ of what I've calculated and stored. If further explanation is needed, I can demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. The task you describe is of course possible. What have you attempted?  GIS SE is a problem-solving site, and all you have so far is a task to be accomplished, without a problem delineated.

Comment: How many points are you processing? Also do you have another dataset that could partition up your points, for example administrative boundaries. Finally do you need you clipped soils raster as one whole dataset or could you live with mini-rasters that are the extent of the buffer, so you would have as many rasters as you have points, hence my question about numbers.

Comment: 1) I have approximately 9000-10000 points overall. 2) I do have another dataset containing the Province boundaries of my study area. (the count is kinda large though since I'm working on a national scale) 3) I need all the data around the points in one whole raster dataset for future steps of my work.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions

### Solution 1

Create a relatively simple model in [model builder](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm) that iterates over your province boundaries, these would select a subset of your point data. You would then create a new buffer layer from those selected points and use that to do the clip, but importantly also use it to set the environment setting, processing extent. You will create as many rasters as you have provinces.

A final step is to mosaic these rasters and you can either mosaic to a new raster (which will probably create a huge unusable raster) or mosaic into a [mosaic dataset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/mosaic-datasets.htm#).

### Solution 2

Looking at your question your appear to be rasterizing the soils dataset first, creating a huge raster. Why don't you just buffer your points and clip the soils vector dataset first and then convert that layer to a raster?

Comment: Solution 2 will work well for this case. thank you so much. While we're at the topic, I also have a contour layer that I have to rasterize. Considering the nature of the process going on with contour rasterization, I can't clip the contours and then calculate the rasterized version. Is there a solution to this one as well? (This layer is the main reason I asked the question above. I used another layer for sake of simplicity delivering my intentions, hoping to get a general solution for any type of vector dataset)

Comment: You need to ask that as a separate question explaining what needs to be clipped, whats doing the clipping and although you might feel its similar your are talking about a different geometry, lines, which have their own topological issues.